# Given a positive integer, tell whether it is equal to the sum of four consecutive integers

Tags: c, math

The problem:

> Given a positive integer, tell whether it is equal to the sum of four consecutive integers.
>
> Input Format:
>   Input consists of a single positive integer,
>
> Output Format:
>   Output consists of a string which is either  "yes" or "no". Print yes when the given number is the sum of four consecutive integers and print no otherwise.
>
> Example:
>   In this example, 2 = -1 + 0 + 1 + 2, and 82 = 19 + 20 + 21 + 22. 5 and 41 are not of the correct
>   form.
>
> Sample Input 1:
>   2
>
> Sample Output 1:
>   yes
>
> Sample Input 2:
>   41
>
> Sample Output 2:
>   no

My program is not being accepted and also for some values my result is being repeated, can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num,sum1=0,index,sum2=0,Soln=0;
    int temp,i;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num <= 0 )
    {
        printf("Wrong Input\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for(index=1;;index++)
    {
        sum1=sum1+index;
        if(sum1>=num)
            break;
    }
    if(sum1 == num )
    {
        if(num == index)
        {
            printf("yes");
            return 0;
        }
        Soln++;
        printf("no" );
        for(temp=1;temp<=index;temp++)
            printf("no");
    }
    for(i=1;i<index;i++)
    {
        sum2+=i;
        if((sum1-sum2) == num )
        {
            if((i+1) == index)
            {
//printf("yes");
                break;
            }
            Soln++;
            printf("no" );
            for(temp= i+1;temp<=index;temp++)
                printf("no");
            break;
        }
    }
    if( Soln == 0 && num >= 9 && num/2 == (num-1)/2 ) //--> if U don't want more       than one ,soln use this 
    //if( num >= 9 && num/2 == (num-1)/2 ) //--> if U want more than one soln, use this
    {
        Soln++;
        printf("no");
    }
    if(Soln==0)
    {
        printf("yes");
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't show much effort to present itself. What do you expect and what is the outcome? Your code is unreadable because a lack of indentation.

Comment: *equal to the sum of four consecutive integers*. i.e. `x = i + (i + 1) + (i + 2) + (i + 3) = 4i + 6`?

Comment: That's just the wrong way to do homework.

Comment: Isn't that more of a mathematical problem anyway?

Comment: @Coder Geek: What algorithm were you trying to implement in your code??? I read and re-read it several times and I don't see how can this sequence of actions can possibly be related to the original statement of the problem. What is the point of summing `1 + 2 + 3 + ...` in the first cycle? What is the point of a cycle that does nothing but prints "no" repeatedly?

Comment: doesn't really matter i think. problem is a problem anyways... and i post it here to clarify it :). thanks for the support though .

Comment: @ Ant : i used the wrong logic.

Comment: The code above is essentially a random piece of meaningless code that was posted here for one purpose only: as an attempt to simulate a genuine "effort". It was done in a hope that someone will simply respond with a complete compilable solution to an obvious homework problem.

Comment: @AnT you probably have become too cynical but I'd say at least directing the OP to rethink the math is a reasonable direction to guide him without providing an outright answer. _Genuine effort_ is also subjective. If someone with no programming background attempted to write brute force code to solve this then oddly enough I'd say the code posted would have been an effort. It definitely wasn't all random code. I could see in parts what he might have been trying to do. I don't think the OP was really hiding the fact this was probably homework as he pasted what appeared the problem asked of him.

Comment: Thanks for understanding me Michael :) i am still learning.

Comment: @CoderGeek - just don't make a habit of solving problems this way, because it can be a great way not to learn ;)

Answer (score 4):

Take the four consecutive integers k, k+1, k+2, and k+3 and sum them up. This yields 4k + 6. If an integer n is the sum of four consecutive integers, it means that n = 4k + 6 for some integer k. Equivalently, this means that n - 6 = 4k for some integer k, or equivalently that (n - 6) mod 4 = 0. That might help you significantly simplify your program.